# Macro for selecting rows containing specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I have large spreadsheet exported from a database with survey responses containing words and phrases of interest, which I'd like to sort and report on. What I would like to do is use a Macro to scan the sentences in the entire sheet and then select only the rows containing the keyword.

Some searching around (http://www.techpository.com/?page_id=1674) led me to this example code, but it gives me errors in Excel 2007:

```
Sub SelectManyRows()
Dim CatchPhrase As String
Dim WholeRange As String
Dim AnyCell As Object
Dim RowsToSelect As String

CatchPhrase = “future”
'first undo any current highlighting
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
WholeRange = "A1:" & ActiveCell.Address
Range(WholeRange).Select
On Error Resume Next 'ignore errors
For Each AnyCell In Selection
If InStr(UCase$(AnyCell.Text), UCase$(CatchPhrase)) Then
If RowsToSelect <> “” Then
RowsToSelect = RowsToSelect & "," 'add group separator
End If
RowsToSelect = RowsToSelect & Trim$(Str$(AnyCell.Row)) & ":" & Trim$(Str$(AnyCell.Row))
End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0 'clear error ‘trap’
Range(RowsToSelect).Select
End Sub
```

The error I get is Run-time '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed... Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

That error is probably being generated by the lines:

```
Range(WholeRange).Select
```

and

```
Range(RowsToSelect).Select
```

because the "Range" object isn't one that just exists on its own... it belongs to a "Worksheet" object, so assuming all of this is happening on the active worksheet (rather than a different one in the background) then try modifying these lines to:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(WholeRange).Select
```

and

```
ActiveSheet.Range(RowsToSelect).Select
```

That should clear the error you're seeing, as long as there aren't any other instances I've missed eyeballing that code. It's worth hitting 'debug' when it throws the error so that you can see which line caused it... try that before and after making these changes to check that the error at least moves!

Full documentation on using Range is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978779%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

HTH